# How do i load a lsp file from standalone C# application into AutoCAD and waiting for it to finish

Tags: c#, .net, autocad, liskov-substitution-principle, autolisp

first time poster here.

I'm building a standalone application in C# where I can drop a set of .dwg's and select which .lsp files I want to run on that set. I can figure out how to open a dwg, load a .lsp file, save the dwg and close it.

What I can't figure out is how do I WAIT for said .lsp file to finish before moving on to the next .dwg.

Answer (score 0):

The Document object has an "LispEnded" EVent.

You can Catch that event, and move to the next document

Regards,
Alain

See example in Manual in Hyperlink : .

[Link to Document Events Handlers](http://docs.autodesk.com/ACD/2013/ENU/index.html?url=files/GUID-4E1AAFA9-740E-4097-800C-CAED09CDFF12.htm,topicNumber=d30e712496)

Comment: Hmm The Link does not display the correct page: Search for: handle document event